# Program is reading in information from text file incorrectly, seemingly left to right, then right to left

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm attempting to read in information about A. A Word, and B. The Frequency of said word. When the function reads in the information the first call reads it in left(Word) to right(Frequency), then the next one is right(Frequency) to left(Word). I'm assuming its due to my formatting. My assumption is that its skipping word.

```py
dicFile << s.key << " " << s.wordCount << endl;
```

dicFile is the text file its being outputted to.
s.key is the word, s.wordcount is an int.

The text file is in format :

Accounting 3

Apple 1

Bread 1

....

gets read by

```py
            fstream dictionaryFile;
            string dF, word, freq;
            cout << "Input dictionary file: ";
            cin >> dF;
            dictionaryFile.open(dF);
            if (dictionaryFile.is_open()) {
                while (dictionaryFile >> word) {
                    dictionaryFile >> word >> freq;
                    int frequ = stoi(freq);
                    newItem.key = word;
                    newItem.wordCount = frequ;
                    tree.AVL_Insert(newItem);
                }
            }
            else { cout << endl << "ERROR"; }
```

It crashes at atoi, im assuming because it cant handle "Accounting".

Comment: `while (dictionaryFile >> word) { dictionaryFile >> word >> freq;` -> You read two times into `word` and then into `freq`. This is not what you intended to do according to your description... (Check this with stepwise execution in your debugger. Watch what appears in `word` and `freq` after first line inside of `while`.)

Comment: That fixed it, thank you.

Comment: IMHO, correct would be `while (dictionaryFile >> word >> freq) {` and then drop the next line completely. (You're welcome.) ;-)

Comment: You may also consider to make `freq` of type `int`. That would make `stoi()` obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it can't handle "Apple".

First, `while (dictionaryFile >> word)` reads "Accounting", and then

```
dictionaryFile >> word >> freq;
```

reads "3" into `word` and "Apple" into `freq`.

What you should do is

```
while (dictionaryFile >> word >> freq) {
    int frequ = stoi(freq);
    // ...
```

or you can remove a bunch of variable-shuffling and read directly into your "item":

```
while (dictionaryFile >> newItem.key >> newItem.wordCount) {
    tree.AVL_Insert(newItem);
}
```